# JBoss Form Based Authentication Failure

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, jboss

I am trying to debug an error I'm getting when I try to login to my JAVA web application. There seems to be some issue with the columns. Here is the stacktrace:

```
anager] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-4) Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.LoginE
xception: PB00019: Processing Failed:Query failed
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DbUtil.getRoleSets(DbUtil.java:166) [pick
etbox-4.0.6.final.jar:4.0.6.final]
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.Util.getRoleSets(Util.java:158) [picketbo
x-4.0.6.final.jar:4.0.6.final]
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule.getRoleSets(Dat
abaseServerLoginModule.java:265) [picketbox-4.0.6.final.jar:4.0.6.final]
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.AbstractServerLoginModule.commit(Abstract
ServerLoginModule.java:228) [picketbox-4.0.6.final.jar:4.0.6.final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1
.7.0_51]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:762)
[rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:2
03) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:690) [
rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:688) [
rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.
7.0_51]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:6
87) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:596) [
rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.de
faultLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:449) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.
6.final.jar:4.0.6.final]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.pr
oceedWithJaasLogin(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:383) [picketbox-infinis
pan-4.0.6.final.jar:4.0.6.final]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.au
thenticate(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:371) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.
6.final.jar:4.0.6.final]
        at org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.is
Valid(JBossCachedAuthenticationManager.java:160) [picketbox-infinispan-4.0.6.fin
al.jar:4.0.6.final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.JBossWebRealm.authenticate(JBossWebRealm.ja
va:215) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(Form
Authenticator.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Authentica
torBase.java:381) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmC
loserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
        at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(Secu
rityContextAssociationValve.java:154) [jboss-as-web-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.j
ava:155) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.j
ava:102) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineVal
ve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.jav
a:368) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java
:877) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.proce
ss(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:93
0) [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1.
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073) [mysql
-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:987) [mysql-
connector-java-5.1.30.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:982) [mysql-
connector-java-5.1.30.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:927) [mysql-
connector-java-5.1.30.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkColumnBounds(ResultSetImpl.java:818
) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:565
1) [mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5570) [mysq
l-connector-java-5.1.30.jar:]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getString(WrappedResultS
et.java:1338)
        at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DbUtil.getRoleSets(DbUtil.java:135) [pick
etbox-4.0.6.final.jar:4.0.6.final]
        ... 31 more
```

Here is my security domain:

```
        <security-domain name="product_app_realm">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                    <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/AuthorityDS"/>
                    <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from product_database.users where username=?"/>
                    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role from product_database.roles where username=?"/>
                </login-module>
            </authentication>
        </security-domain>
```

Any idea what the issue may be, is there a problem with my security domain setup? The root of the problem seems to point at an issue with my columns in either the users or roles table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return two values from the `rolesQuery`.

> The prepared statement query equivalent to: select Role, RoleGroup
>   from Roles where PrincipalID=?. If not specified this is the exact
>   prepared statement that will be used.

Try changing your query to

```
select role, 'Roles' from product_database.roles where username=?
```

Answer (score 1):

The `rolesQuery` expects to retrieve TWO columns. JBoss will only use the records where the second column value is `Roles`.

It is used so you can use the same table to store other "roles" together with the ones used for JBoss. Tricky, but such column appear clearly at all the examples.

More info:
http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/getting_started/v2/startguide40/security.html